# Javascript - How to show escape characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, escaping

Very simple question, but for some reason I can't find the answer anywhere after 10 minutes of Googling. How can I show escape characters when printing in Javascript?

Example:

```
str = "Hello\nWorld";
console.log(str);
```

Gives:

```
Hello
World
```

When I want it to give:

```
Hello\nWorld
```

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate, but I think the answer that everyone expects is here. :)

Comment: I'd like to add the answer that one can simply use `String.raw\`Hello\nWorld\``  but this question has been incorrectly marked as duplicate

Answer (score 143, accepted):

If your goal is to create a string using a string literal like this:

```
str = "Hello\nWorld";
```

and output what it contains *in string literal form* (a fairly specific use case), you can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(str)); // ""Hello\nWorld""
```

```js
const str = "Hello\nWorld";
const json = JSON.stringify(str);
console.log(json); // ""Hello\nWorld""
for (let i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {
    console.log(`${i}: ${json.charAt(i)} (0x${json.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(4, "0")})`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

This is a fairly unusual thing to want to do, though helpful sometimes for debugging in awkward situations where, for whatever reason, you can't use a debugger directly.

`console.log` adds the outer quotes (at least in Chrome's implementation), but the content within them is a string literal (yes, that's somewhat confusing).

`JSON.stringify` takes what you give it (in this case, a string) and returns a string containing valid JSON for that value. So for the above, it returns an opening quote (`"`), the word `Hello`, a backslash (`\`), the letter `n`, the word `World`, and the closing quote (`"`). The linefeed in the string is escaped in the output as a `\` and an `n` because that's how you encode a linefeed in JSON. Other escape sequences are similarly encoded.

---

To be clear, if you just want to create a string with `H`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`, `\`, `n`, `W`, `o`, `r`, `l`, `d` in it, you **don't** need `JSON.stringify` for that. Just escape the backslash so it's not treated as an escape character: `"Hello\\nWorld"`

```js
console.log("Hello\\nWorld");
```

The `JSON.stringify` thing is just for situations where you want to see a string-literal-like output for a string with things like newlines in it, usually for debugging.

Comment: This did the job, thanks!

The reason I accepted this answer is because it works with non-literal strings and doesn't involve modifying the string itself.

Comment: but if we don't use an existing special character (combined with the backslash) js will trim it out before the stringify 
`console.log(JSON.stringify("asdasd\Sasdasd")); // "asdasdSasdasd"`
`console.log("asdasd\Sasdasd"); // asdasdSasdasd`

Comment: @icosamuel - There is no backslash in that string. `"asdasd\Sasdasd"` is `"asdasdSasdasd"`. When you escape a character that doesn't have special meaning, the result is just the character. Put it another way, `"\S".length` is 1, because that defines a one-character string with an S in it, exactly like `"S"` does.

Comment: interesting! Is there any way to treat them as cleartext outside of escaping the original backslash? `\\S`

Comment: @icosamuel - Not with a string literal; as soon as the string literal is parsed, that ``\`` is gone because it has no meaning. If you use a template literal, you can use the `String.raw` tagged template function: `String.raw\`\S\`` (notice that those are backticks, not quotes) returns `"\\S"`.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using JSON.stringify on anything other than objects, this is super-helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @BobStein - Done!

Comment: Could not detect ASCII 160. Someone else might be scratching their head with this. It is a space character that originates form HTML nbsp. You can use charCodeAt() function to verify the same.

Comment: @SanjayVamja - Yes, that's [U+00A0](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=00A0), the primary non-breaking space. The escape for it in a JavaScript string literal is `\xA0` or `\u00A0`, but it's perfectly valid as a literal character.

Comment: This question ranks high in Google but it's important to know that this accepted answer serves a very ultra-specific use case (dump double quotes and line feeds in a string you got from somewhere else). You don't need any of this if you are merely composing your own string literal.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - I've updated to try to make that clear, thanks for the head's up.

Answer (score 29):

JavaScript uses the \ (backslash) as an escape characters for:

- \' single quote
- \" double quote
- \ backslash
- \n new line
- \r carriage return
- \t tab
- \b backspace
- \f form feed
- \v vertical tab (IE < 9 treats '\v' as 'v' instead of a vertical tab ('\x0B'). If cross-browser compatibility is a concern, use \x0B instead of \v.)
- \0 null character (U+0000 NULL) (only if the next character is not a decimal digit; else it’s an octal escape sequence)

**Note that the \v and \0 escapes are not allowed in JSON strings.**

Answer (score 22):

You have to escape the backslash, so try this:

```
str = "Hello\\nWorld";
```

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript) are more escaped characters in Javascript.

Comment: Only this one works for backslash -stringify does not especially if you put it alone.