# Write HTML Special Character into a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$("<h2/>", {"class" : "wi wi"+data.today.code}).text(" " + data.city + data.today.temp.now + "F").appendTo(custom_example);`

Hi there, I'm trying to alter the code above to add the degrees icon just before the (F)arenheit marker. I've tried entering `+ html("&#176;") +` but it doesn't work. My JS is pretty rough and I was hoping I could get a quick answer here before I spent too long trying and failing. Thanks!

I want the end result to print something like: **Encinitas 65°F**

Comment: Just change it to `… + "°F"`. The character isn't that special at all.

Comment: What is that `html` function you were calling?

Comment: Is that a valid jQuery selector, having an actual element with angle brackets?

Comment: Use .html() function instead of .text(), because text() escapes any HTML that is passed into it.

Comment: Just use the "degree" character, then? What's stopping you?

Comment: you have to hard-code it using text(), it will work with html().

Comment: When I put in "°F", it displays on the client side as:
65Â°F

Comment: Add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to your HTML file's header.

Answer (score 6):

Special characters are characters that must be escaped by a backslash`\`, like:

- Single quote `\'`
- Double quote `\"`
- Backslash `\\`

The degree ° is not a special character, you can just write it, as it is.

**Edit**: If you want to use the `unicode` of °F, just write: `'\u2109'`.

Comment: That's what I initially thought but it is coming through as "65Â°F". Not sure what is going on.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. Didn't know there was a unicode of °F.

Comment: You are welcome! If it did the trick please mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

[Escape Special Characters JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672439/8555754)

JavaScript uses the \ (backslash) as an escape characters for:

- \' single quote
- \" double quote
- \ backslash
- \n new line
- \r carriage return
- \t tab
- \b backspace
- \f form feed
- \v vertical tab (IE < 9 treats '\v' as 'v' instead of a vertical tab
  ('\x0B').
- If cross-browser compatibility is a concern, use \x0B instead of \v.)
  \0 null character (U+0000 NULL) (only if the next character is not a
  decimal digit; else it’s an octal escape sequence)

Note that the \v and \0 escapes are not allowed in JSON strings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the degree character needs not to be escaped. So simply entering `"°F"` should do the job.

However, if you are in doubt with the codepage of your JS code you could use a *JavaScript* escape sequence. JS escape sequences are quite different from HTML escapes. The do not support decimal values at all. So first of all you have to convert `176` to hex: `b0`. The correctly escaped equivalent to `"°F"` is `"\xb0F"`. It will work too and is more robust with respect to codepage issues of you platform's source editor.

If you really want to assign HTML code you need to use the `.html()` function. But this is mutual exclusive to `.text()`. So in this case *all* of your content needs to be HTML rather than plain text. Otherwise an HTML injection  vulnerability arises. I.e. you need to properly escape angle brackets and some other symbols in `data.city` and maybe `data.today.temp.now` as well.

JS itself has no built-in function to escape HTML. But JQuery provides a trick: `$('&lt;div/&gt;').text(data.city).html()` will return appropriately escaped HTML. See [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-lost-when-attribute-read-from-input-field) for more details.

I would recommend not to use `.html()` unless you really need it, e.g. if you want to apply styles or formatting to *parts* of the text only.