# Write "xxx\n" into a file, but with the "\n" being OS-compatible

Tags: javascript, file, newline

I am implementing a NodeJS script which auto-generates JavaScript code.

I need to write `"xxx\n"` somewhere in the auto-generated JavaScript file.

But I want the `\n` part to be OS-compatible.

I've figured I should use `require("os").EOL`, for example:

```
let EOL = require("os").EOL;
let str = `xxx${EOL}`;
...
// write str into the file
```

But that writes a **real** newline into the file.

How can I convert that `EOL` into an actual string, like `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`?

P.S.:

For performance considerations, I wish to avoid plugging `require("os").EOL` into the auto-generated file (i.e., I want the newline to be "hard-coded" in there).

Comment: `JSON.stringify(require("os").EOL).slice(1, -1)`, but this does seem an odd thing to do.

Comment: UNIX master race, who cares about CRLF

Comment: Just an idea, you could check what EOL is, like `if(EOL === "\r\n") { str = 'xxx\r\n'; } elseif ...` and so on. Bit hacky ... ;)

Comment: @eisbehr  Also you of course meant, -. `xx\\r\\n`

Comment: @Keith: That's a pretty neat idea!!!

Comment: @Keith: Yes, I did (I mean, at present, I am using `"\\n"` in my auto-generating script).

Comment: https://github.com/ryanve/eol uses `isWindows = typeof process != 'undefined' && 'win32' === process.platform`. Would that be viable?

Comment: @KooiInc: That would be rather nasty IMO. I prefer not to plug "windows related" code into my script. What if there's another OS out there with the same properties but a different newline sequence?

Comment: @goodvibration, I agree. Another question may be why line endings in javascript (albeit generate) are actually relevant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - How to show escape characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672334/javascript-how-to-show-escape-characters-in-a-string)