# JS show special ascii characters in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, ascii, special-characters

Is there a way to make this string:

```
foo
    bar
```

Appear like this:

```
foo\r\n\tbar
```

It would really help with debugging a lexer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - How to show escape characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672334/javascript-how-to-show-escape-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: yup, my bad, didn't search for escaped characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to escape `\n` in a string replace.

```js
let specialCharacters = [
    {regex: /\n/g, replacement: '\\n'},
    {regex: /\t/g, replacement: '\\t'}
];

function escapeSpecialCharacters(str){
  specialCharacters.forEach(c => {
    str = str.replace(c.regex, c.replacement);
  });
  return str;
}

console.log(escapeSpecialCharacters(`test
test
test
1234`));
```

Comment: right, right, but is there a way to just show all the special characters without manually replacing every single one of them?

Comment: There is a finite number of them, and it's not even that large, unless you're counting Unicode symbols.

Comment: As far as I know, 'special characters' is not some canonical class of characters that has a well-known definition.  Why not make a list of all the special characters you care about.. that would be easier I think.

Comment: There, I've added the means for you to extend my solution with more special characters.  Also, I've fixed my solution so that it replaces *all* occurrences of a special character.  Before, it was replacing only the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

If debugging is all you want to do, you can display all escaped characters it in the browser console, but putting the string into an array:

```js
let string = "test\ntest";

let arr = [];

arr.push(string);

console.log(arr);
```

But that will not change your string in any way, it still contains new line, instead of "\n".