# How to change "&amp;" to just "&" in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, java

```
var $dtTable = $("#dtItemMaster").DataTable();

$dtTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(dtRow).addClass('selected');

var dtRowData = $dtTable.row(dtRow).data();

$("#txtItemCode").val(dtRowData[1]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - How to show escape characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672334/javascript-how-to-show-escape-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex

```
$("#txtItemCode").val(dtRowData[1].replace(/&amp;/g, "&"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
var elem = document.createElement('textarea');
elem.innerHTML = "&amp;";
var decoded = elem.value;

$("#txtItemCode").val(decoded);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtItemCode" />
```

Comment: did you try var elem = document.createElement('textarea');
elem.innerHTML = dtRowData[1]