# Javascript - how to handle the single quote?

Tags: javascript

When i click the following it fails.

php render/html:

```
<div class="a" onclick="test('25', 'l'Espagne')" >
```

js:

```
function test(id, name) {
  alert(name); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the quote mark with a \ whenever you need a single quote inside of a pair of single quotes. This also works for double quotes, if needed.

```js
function test(id, name) {
  alert(name);
}
```

```html
<div class="a" onclick="test('25', 'l\'Espagne')">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: Only offered my answer for coverage, but this is my vote

Answer (score 2):

You can use template literals if you're not worried about supporting old browsers (incl. IE):

```js
function test(id, name) {
  alert(name);
}
```

```html
<div class="a" onclick="test('25', `l'Espagne`)">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape it with a backslash

```
test('25', 'l\'Espagne')
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape it with a back slash "\".
For example,

```
test('25', 'l\'Espagne')
```

For more information on escape characters, see

- \' single quote
- \" double quote
- \ backslash
- \n new line
- \r carriage return
- \t tab
- \b backspace
- \f form feed
- \v vertical tab (IE < 9 treats '\v' as 'v' instead of a vertical tab ('\x0B'). If cross-browser compatibility is a concern, use \x0B instead of \v.)
- \0 null character (U+0000 NULL) (only if the next character is not a decimal digit; else it’s an octal escape sequence)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672439