# Format string to display \n and add space for tabs

Tags: javascript, string

How can I transform a string to display newlines (`\n`) and tabs using javascript?

Example Input

```
// Get position of the element clicked
var getPosition = function(element) {
    var xP = (element.offsetLeft + element.clientLeft);
    var yP = (element.offsetTop + element.clientTop);
    return {x: xP, y: yP};
};
```

*Expected Output*

```
// Get position of the element clicked\nvar getPosition = function(element) {\n    var xP = (element.offsetLeft + element.clientLeft);\n    var yP = (element.offsetTop + element.clientTop);\n    return {x: xP, y: yP};\n};\n\n
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - How to show escape characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672334/javascript-how-to-show-escape-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `JSON.stringify(str)` like so:

```js
const input = `// Get position of the element clicked
var getPosition = function(element) {
    var xP = (element.offsetLeft + element.clientLeft);
    var yP = (element.offsetTop + element.clientTop);
    return {x: xP, y: yP};
};

`;

console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
```