# How to write \r as text in html using js function by createElement of pre tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a case where i have to show \r at the end of a string in a javascript function but the \r does not show.

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a PRE element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("pre");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World\r");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Expected result: Hello World\r

Comment: You need to escape the backslash - `var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World\\r");`

Comment: It should "show" as a carriage return if you don't escape the backslash. You can't see it but it's there

Comment: `\r` is a [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#escape_sequences). To get a literal backslash, you need to escape it too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - How to show escape characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672334/javascript-how-to-show-escape-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: Beware that the accepted answer in the question linked by @Kaddath solves a very specific use case (input already contains actual carriage returns and we want them dumped as entities) that doesn't really apply here (or, to the honest, to the concrete question it answers).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It true, I haven't been careful enough when [I tested in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLte40rv/): it correctly escapes the character, but it also adds quotes to the displayed string (I actually don't really know why)

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution by adding one more \ before \r.
eg.

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a PRE element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("pre");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World\\r");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```